# Polly C# retry exponentially for 3 tries then switch to retrying every hour

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, exponential-backoff, policywrap

I am trying to use polly to construct a policy that can retry exponentially for n tries and then switch to retrying every 1 hour. Can this be achieved?

I tried policy Wrap but did not get the desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible to achieve with overloads accepting [custom `sleepDurationProvider`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait). For example something like the following:

```cs
var waitAndRetry = Policy
    .Handle<SomeException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(4, retryAttempt => retryAttempt switch // or WaitAndRetryForever
    {
        <= 3 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)), // for example n == 3
        _ => TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party but let me share my thoughts:

> construct a policy that can retry exponentially for n tries
> Here is an example how you can construct

```
var retryWithBackoff = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), n));
```

- You need to use the [Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry) to be able to use `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2`

  - [Here](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry/blob/master/README.md#wait-and-retry-with-jittered-back-off) you can find a good explanation how does this exponential backoff with jitter work
  - Please adjust the `medianFirstRetryDelay` parameter for your needs
- Please also adjust the trigger for your need

> retrying every 1 hour

```
var retryForeverWithAnHourDelay = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

- I've used retry forever because based on your requirements it seems like you want to retry until it succeeds
- I've used async to avoid blocking for an hour while the policy sleeps

> I tried policy Wrap

```
var combinedRetryPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryForeverWithAnHourDelay, retryWithBackoff);
```

- Please note the ordering

  - the left hand side parameter is the outer policy
  - the right hand side parameter is the inner policy
- In other words if `retryWithBackoff` did not success then try `retryForeverWithAnHourDelay`

---

Here you can find a simple dotnet fiddle app which demonstrates this at work:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQihRk
- Please note that dotnet fiddle will terminate the app after 10 seconds

---

#### Final thoughts

Even though it is feasible to sleep for an hour with Polly, it is not suggested. Polly's retry was primarily designed to overcome transient failures. These failures should vanish/self-heal in minutes (not in hours or days).

If you need to wait that long I would rather suggest to use some sort of job scheduler like [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: I have tried policy wrap but that does not give the desired results.

Comment: @etiaggarwal Could you please elaborate on this? What is the desired result? What is the observed?

Comment: With policy wrap the code retries 3 times and then sleeps for an hour and then again retries 3 times and so on... I just wanted to switch the timing after 3 retries.

Comment: @etiaggarwal Are you talking about your code or mine?